# Electron - React Router points to wrong url after building

Tags: react-router, electron, react-router-dom, electron-builder

I've built an app with Electron that displays React pages. I'm using react-router-dom v6 to switch between tabs. When I run the app with *npm start* everything works fine, however, after *npm run build* (I use electron-builder), the path starts with /C:/ and therefore does not render the correct page.

[image: Text]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this was very easy to fix. Instead of `BrowserRouter` I just used `HashRouter` and everything works perfectly.